# Teradata DB can be queried using SSMS

Tags: ssms, teradata

I have data residing in Teradata DB. I am comfortable with SSMS more than Teradata SQL assistant to query data. Is it possible to query Teradata DB using SSMS?

Comment: Sql Server Managment Studio? Maybe as a linked server?  But probably not.

Comment: Before setting up the connection from the SQL Server configure the same connection for Teradata needs to be configured in ODBC Data Source Administrator. Since you are talking only about querying the data from TD this should help: https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/teradata-odbc-linked-server.rst